# Bluetooth device 'Connection reset by peer' when attempting to pair via python

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, rssi

I am connecting to a Raspberry Pi from my computer via the following code.

```
import bluetooth

MACaddr = 'F0:65:DD:6B:81:FD'
#Mac address of Raspberry Pi used in test
port = 1

print "Device found!\n Pairing with device."

sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket (bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock.connect((MACaddr, port))
```

My plan is to have my laptop connect to two Raspberry Pis. The Pis will then calculate my approximate distance in between with the RSSI value of my laptop.

When I run 'sudo hcitool rssi F0:65:DD:6B:81:FD'
For about 30 seconds I will receive the returned RSSI value but after about 30 seconds the python program returns:

```
File "bt.py", line 12, in <module>
sock.connect((MACaddr, port))
File "<string>", line 5, in connect
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (104, 'Connection reset by peer')
```

Comment: It seems to be crashing at 'sock.connect((MACaddr, port))' when messing around with it nothing after that is executed.

Comment: You are using PyBluez, I assume.  You really need to state the version.  From what I recall, hcitool is calling ioctl and drivers directly, while pybluez calls the dbus interface -- so if you don't have dbus running and configured correctly, it just hangs and eventually gives up.  There were so many bugs with the version I was using, I ended up writing my own python module wrapping the ioctl calls, (it allows you to access higher-level protocols which aren't implemented in bluez).  -- So I would recommend you check your syslogs and dbus logs as a start.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't recommend using the RSSI to estimate distances, especially at such low signal levels.  There are more accurate ways using triangulation, (but then you have to move around to get a fix).  But if you want a way that avoids ioctl AND bluez, there is a nice little driver database in /var/lib/bluetooth/<mac-id> where you can get that information from files after you run the hcitool command to populate and call hcitool through a subprocess command.